# Vagrant up not installing ImageMagick correctly

Tags: php, vagrant

I'm trying to set up my config.yaml such that I can use PHP's ImageMagick library immediately after performing a vagrant up. Currently the only way I can get it to work is by installing all the packages manually after booting the server and SSH'ing in. When trying to install via vagrant up, it installs the packages, but PHP doesn't recognize the library for whatever reason.

I'm using Vagrant 1.8.4.

Here's the relevant configurations I did in my config.yaml:

**Server Config**

```
server:
install: '1'
packages:
    - vim
    - htop
    - git
    - tmux
    - pv
    - imagemagick
```

**PHP Config**

```
php:
install: '1'
settings:
    version: '55'
modules:
    php:
        - cli
        - cgi
        - intl
        - imagick
    pear: {  }
    pecl: {  }
ini:
    engine=On: '0'
    engine: 'On'
    short_open_tag: 'On' # We still use this in some places; also (bad) libraries might use this
    asp_tags: 'Off'
    precision: '14'
    output_buffering: '4096'
    zlib.output_compression: 'Off'
    implicit_flush: 'Off'
    serialize_precision: '17'
    disable_functions: 'pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_│+ wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,'
    zend.enable_gc: 'On'
    expose_php: 'On'
    max_execution_time: '30'
    max_input_time: '60'
    memory_limit: 128M
    error_reporting: 'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING'
    display_errors: 'Off'              # Only turn on in personal VM
    display_startup_errors: 'Off'      # Only turn on in personal VM
    log_errors: 'On'
    log_errors_max_len: '1024'
    error_log: /var/log/php/php.log # We have to log errors to a place that has write permissions for www-user (Apache user)
    ignore_repeated_errors: 'Off'
    ignore_repeated_source: 'Off'
    report_memleaks: 'On'
    track_errors: 'Off'
    html_errors: 'On'
    variables_order: GPCS
    request_order: GP
    register_argc_argv: 'Off'
    auto_globals_jit: 'On'
    post_max_size: 8M
    default_mimetype: text/html
    enable_dl: 'Off'
    file_uploads: 'On'
    upload_max_filesize: 2M
    max_file_uploads: '20'
    allow_url_fopen: 'On'
    allow_url_include: 'Off'
    default_socket_timeout: '60'
    cli_server.color: 'On'
    SMTP: localhost
    smtp_port: '25'
    mail.add_x_header: 'On'
    sql.safe_mode: 'Off'
    odbc.allow_persistent: 'On'
    odbc.check_persistent: 'On'
    odbc.max_persistent: '-1'
    odbc.max_links: '-1'
    odbc.defaultlrl: '4096'
    odbc.defaultbinmode: '1'
    ibase.allow_persistent: '1'
    ibase.max_persistent: '-1'
    ibase.max_links: '-1'
    ibase.timestampformat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    ibase.dateformat: '%Y-%m-%d'
    session.save_handler: files
    session.use_cookies: '1'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What provisioner are you using for the vagrant box? chef? puppet? ansible? docker? other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference, it turned out we were installing php5-imagick instead of php5.6-imagick, which made a huge difference. I'm not sure why installing via apt-get handled this difference better.